# What is cargo build-bpf?

Tags: cargo, build-bpf

The [solana-program-library](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library) says to build apps with `cargo build-bpf` yet if you look at `cargo --help` this is not mentioned as a valid argument. How does cargo know to look at `BPF SDK: /home/phil/Downloads/solana-1.10.8/bin/sdk/bpf` Why don't you build with `cargo b` like most Rust apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cargo --list` does contain the `build-bpf`

It is a cargo tool that is a super set of `build`. What is does is take the LLVM output of `build` (i.e. `rustc`) and **transpiles** it into BPF which is the acceptable form for a Solana program to run on the chain.